# unicity solution of partial differential equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

let the following problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}= a^2 \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\\
u(0,t)=u(l,t)=0\\
u(x,0)=f(x)\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,0)=g(x)
\end{cases}
$$

The questions are: 
We put $f=g=0$, and we multiply the equation by $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, we integrate on $[0,l]$ and we use $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial t} w = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} |w|^2$.

1. How we prouve that $$\dfrac{1}{2} \displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\{(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t})^2 + (\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2\} dx =0$$
2. We put $I(t)= \dfrac{1}{2} \displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\{(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t})^2 + (\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2\} dx =0$, prouve that $I(t)=I(0)$ and deduce the unicity solution of the problem.

I try this: we have
$$
\displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} dt = a^2 \displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} . \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial u}{\partial t} dt
$$
We have:
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} |\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}|^2
$$
But what about $\displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} . \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} dx$?

Thank's for the help.